# Why does the Chrome devtool shows the object attributes and the object itself differently?

Tags: javascript, object

```
const a = {
  age: 12,
  name: 'Lucy'
};

console.log(a, a.age);

delete(a.age);
```

Can anyone explain to me what happens to the `age` property when I `console.log` it in Chrome dev tool and the result shows up like this?

```
Object {age: 12, name: "Lucy"} 12
  name:"lucy"
  __proto__:Object
```

And if I define another object and `console.log` it.

```
const b = {
  age: 12,
  name: 'lucy'
};

console.log(b);
```

The console prints all the property it has?

```
Object {age: 12, name: "lucy"}
  age:12
  name:"lucy"
  __proto__:Object
```

Comment: It does as what you did since you called [`delete(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete), like _delete_ it. But your question body is different than the title. It should correspond to each other. So I'm not sure what you want to ask. Do you want to know how the `delete()` works or why `b` has still the `age` property ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's because you `console.log` that object before you delete its property.

`Object {age: 12, name: "Lucy"}` is just a quick object snapshot done by Chrome devtool. It won't change whatever you did right after.

And when you expand to show object attributes, devtool link to object reference and shows current value.

Comment: Right, I see,  so it's the chrome snapshot and the object reference. Thx mate